# Set GDI page settings for printing C++

Tags: c++, printing, gdi

I am having trouble setting the "default" page size for my document. I am using Visual C++ on Windows, with GDI calls (required for backward-compatibility).

So far my basic approach is to get a default `DEVMODE`, set the properties on it that I want, and then prompt the user if he wants to change it. But it seems to make no difference on the page size. It works on Orientation.

What am I doing wrong?

```
HDC GetPrinterDC () {
    // Initialize device
    PRINTDLG pd = {0};
    pd.lStructSize = sizeof( pd );
    pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT;
    PrintDlg(&pd);

    // If device initialization failed, abort
    if (pd.hDevMode == NULL) return NULL;

    // Get the actual memory pointer
    PDEVMODE dm = (PDEVMODE)GlobalLock(pd.hDevMode);
    if (dm) {
        // Set any properties that are specific for our document
        if (dm->dmFields & DM_ORIENTATION)
            dm->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;

        if (dm->dmFields & DM_PAPERSIZE)
            dm->dmPaperSize = 0;

        if (dm->dmFields & DM_PAPERLENGTH)
            dm->dmPaperLength = 3302; // 13in

        if (dm->dmFields & DM_PAPERWIDTH)
            dm->dmPaperWidth = 4572; // 18in

        GlobalUnlock(pd.hDevMode);
    }

    // Initialize a PRINTDLG structure.
    pd.hwndOwner = GetForegroundWindow();
    pd.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_HIDEPRINTTOFILE | PD_DISABLEPRINTTOFILE | PD_NOPAGENUMS | PD_NOSELECTION | PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE ;

    // Retrieve the printer DC
    HDC hdc = NULL;
    if (PrintDlg(&pd)) hdc = pd.hDC;

    // Free the resources allocated
    if (pd.hDevMode != NULL) GlobalFree(pd.hDevMode);
    if (pd.hDevNames != NULL) GlobalFree(pd.hDevNames);

    return hdc;
}
```

Comment: I thought it gives the current default settings for the current default printer - what are you saying it does?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can specify `dmFields` in the `DEVMODE` struct to be anything you want.

The code should look like this:

```
    PDEVMODE dm = (PDEVMODE)GlobalLock(pd.hDevMode);
    if (dm) {
        // Set any properties that are specific for our document
        dm->dmFields = dm->dmFields | DM_ORIENTATION | DM_PAPERSIZE
            | DM_PAPERLENGTH | DM_PAPERWIDTH;
        dm->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
        dm->dmPaperSize = 0;
        dm->dmPaperLength = 3302; // 13in
        dm->dmPaperWidth = 4572; // 18in

        GlobalUnlock(pd.hDevMode);
    }
```